# FirebaseAnimatedList throwing exception " Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null' " for each row after signout

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When a user signs out of Firebase, they get this error for each row in the database sent to the console.

```
firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'
  at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:58196/dart_sdk.js:5397:11)
    at Object.castError (http://localhost:58196/dart_sdk.js:5356:15)
    at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:58196/dart_sdk.js:5677:17)
    at String.as (http://localhost:58196/dart_sdk.js:46273:19)
    at Object.getProperty (http://localhost:58196/dart_sdk.js:62760:14)
    at Object.convertFirebaseDatabaseException (http://localhost:58196/packages/firebase_database_web/src/interop/database.dart.lib.js:1319:27)
    at http://localhost:58196/packages/firebase_database_web/src/interop/database.dart.lib.js:290:67
    at Object._checkAndCall (http://localhost:58196/dart_sdk.js:5600:16)
    at Object.dcall (http://localhost:58196/dart_sdk.js:5605:17)
    at ret (http://localhost:58196/dart_sdk.js:62582:21)
    at Xs.onCancel (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-database.js:1:132352)
```

I've gotten this down to the simplest example. Even if I navigate to another page right after signout, this still appears.

I've also gotten this error with more complex examples (like using Riverpod with controllers and repository architecture).

It seems that if i have anything stream like coming from the database, when I signout i get this error. I feel there is something fundamental I am not understanding about closing these streams properly.

Here's the FirebaseAnimatedList I'm using:

```dart
body: Column(children: [  
    Expanded(  
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(  
          query: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('msg'),  
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,  
              Animation<double> animation, int index) {  
              return ListTile(  
                title: Text("message.content"),  
              );  
          }),  
    ),  
  
]  
)
```

Here's all the code:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<UserCredential> _signIn() async {
    print('init app');
    return Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    ).then((value) async {
      print('signing in');
      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: "a@b.com",
        password: "mypassword",
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder<UserCredential>(
        future: _signIn(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text("Error signing in: ${snapshot.error}"),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const StateHome();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StateHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const StateHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StateHome> createState() => _StateHomeState();
}

class _StateHomeState extends State<StateHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Home"),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
              onPressed: () async {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) => print('logged out'));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                  query: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('msg'),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                      Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text("message.content"),
                      );
                  }),
            ),

        ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried navigating away from the screen on signout, using Riverpod with controller and repository classes for the messages. I've used a `ListView.builder` instead of FirebasedAnimatedList.  All get the same exception when `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to use a StreamBuilder so i can monitor `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`.  I also tried something similar with Riverpod StreamProvider and got that to work too.

This makes sense since you need to display something on log out.  Even if you are changing to a different page right away, you need to have your stream controlled by `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`.

```
   body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // The user is signed in
          return Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                  query: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('msg'),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                      Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text("message.content"),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          // The user is not signed in, show a different widget
          return const Center(
            child: Text('Please sign in'),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
```